# Including aws-java-sdk jar in Production

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

The only feature of AWS that we are going to use is `s3`. I have the `aws-java-sdk-<ver>.jar` which is ~14MB jar. Is there a standalone jar available for just using `s3` (I mean the core components and s3 features)?

I looked up on the web, tried combination of names (appended s3 to links etc.) but couldn't find any. However, I stumbled upon this page : [JARs for Android](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JXN6FGS5Y2L1/Understanding-the-JARs-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android). There are feature specific jars for aws on Andorid. I have a feeling that they would have something similar for the regular java sdk as well. Has someone come across that or my only resort is to include the 14 MB jar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has been addressed with the [AWS SDK for Java 1.9.0](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/7291607733354976) release in the meantime:

> Starting from 1.9.0 version, the SDK Maven project got split into multiple Maven modules. It allows you to pick up only a small subset of the SDK according to which AWS services you need to work with.

The split is basically 'one module per service', allowing to import only a core module `aws-java-sdk-core`, along with the one (or more) service specific module(s) actually needed, e.g. `aws-java-sdk-s3`.